# GCM 2.0 is not working in Android P

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, push

I'm  implementing GCM in Android P.
But I cannot receive the broadcasting from GCM.
What's wrong in Android P?
By the way, working well in Android O.

```
    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    registrationIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gsf");
    registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", sender_id);
    registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));

public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        Log.e("GCM", "action=" + intent.getAction() + " registration_id="+intent.getStringExtra("registration_id"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of GCM are you using? Does the quoted registrationIntent come from the library?

Comment: Is GCM even supported? Switch to firebase to adapt to new background process restrictions applicable from Android P.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be using an older version of GCM.

Upgrade to GCM 11 or higher. (The latest is 15.0.1: com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1), or even better, migrate to FCM. (GCM is now deprecated)

Answer (score 3):

the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest) states ...

> As of April 10, 2018, Google has deprecated GCM. The GCM server and client APIs are deprecated and **will be removed as soon as April 11, 2019**. Migrate GCM apps to [Firebase Cloud Messaging](http://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (FCM), which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus many new features. See the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) to learn more.

therefore, you might (sooner or later) have to migrate to `FCM`.

since recently, there's also [Firebase In-App Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/in-app-messaging/).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself by using GCM 3.0 way like below:

```
public void getInstanceIdToken() {
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}

public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {
    private static String TAG = RegistrationIntentService.class.getSimpleName();

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    String senderId = "YourSenderId";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        try {
            String token = instanceID.getToken(senderId,
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```